# post different tweet's with their respective image with tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I don't know how to post a different tweets with image.

I have a txt with the tweets(3) I want to post and 3 images to post:

- tweet 1 with image 1
- tweet 2 with image 2
- tweet 3 with image 3

but my code post the same tweet with all images.

```
my_file = open('tweets.txt','r')

file_lines = my_file.readlines()

my_file.close

filenames = ['IMG/img1.jpg','IMG/img2.jpg','IMG/img3.png']

for line in file_lines:
    for filename in filenames:
        imagePath = filename
        api.update_with_media(imagePath,line)
        filenames = filenames[1:]
        nap = randint(1,60)
        time.sleep(nap)
```

Comment: Weloce to Stack Overflow! I edited your question formatting the code properly. A well-formatted question without spelling errors results more readable to other users, so it's more likely that they'll read your question and maybe give an answer. If you want, you can have a look into the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) while you wait for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code to let you see what is going on:

```
tweets = ["tweet 1", "tweet 2", "tweet 3"]
images = ["image 1", "image 2", "image 3"]

for t in tweets:
    for i in images:
        print(t + " with " + i)
        images = images[1:]
```

**Output:**

```
tweet 1 with image 1
tweet 1 with image 2
tweet 1 with image 3
```

**What is going on?**

you have two `for` loops, one inside the other, saying:

> For each tweet, for each image, show me tweet + image, then remove the
>   first image in the list

So what your program does is:

```
# first iteration of 'tweets' list
tweet = "tweet 1"
# first iteration of 'images' list
image = "image 1"
print tweet + image # ("tweet 1" and "image 1")
# remove first image from 'images' ("images 1")

# second iteration of 'images' list (notice that tweet is still "tweet 1")
image = "image 2"
print tweet + image # ("tweet 1" and "image 2")
# remove first image from 'images' ("images 2")


# third iteration of 'images' list (notice that tweet is still "tweet 1")
image = "image 3"
print tweet + image # ("tweet 1" and "image 2")
# remove first image from 'images' ("images 3")


# second iteration of 'tweets' list
tweet = "tweet 2"
# 'images' list is now empty, so nothing will be iterated (nor printed)

# third iteration of 'tweets' list
tweet = "tweet 3"
# 'images' list is now empty, so nothing will be iterated (nor printed)
```

**So what to do ?**

Assuming the lists have the same length `n`, you can select your items by the index, from `0` to `n-1`:

```
tweets = ["tweet 1", "tweet 2", "tweet 3"]
images = ["image 1", "image 2", "image 3"]

for n in range(len(images)):
    print(tweets[n] + " with " + images[n])
```

output:

```
tweet 1 with image 1
tweet 2 with image 2
tweet 3 with image 3
```

If you want to go a step further, Python have a built-in that *zips* together 2 lists: the function [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
tweets = ["tweet 1", "tweet 2", "tweet 3"]
images = ["image 1", "image 2", "image 3"]

my_tweets = zip(tweets, images)

for tweet, image in my_tweets:
    print(tweet + " with " + image)
```

There are many other solutions, but this 2 should work fine for you. Use the first if you won't need these tweets any more in the code; if you're going to use them again, go with `zip`.

*Up to you doing the last step to actually post the tweets. Good luck!*